# Firebase to BigQuery intraday table 48 hour delay

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Currently having an issue with BigQuery where intraday tables are being processed in 48 hours instead of the usual 24 hours for data from Firebase. This is resulting in us seeing 2 intraday tables for today and the previous day and 59 events tables instead of the default 60. This started happening a few days ago and didn't have any issues with this prior. There hasn't been any new apps linked within firebase in that time which other tickets indicate could be an issue.

Have checked logging and monitoring for BigQuery in GCP and didn't see any service errors that may have caused this or any long delays that may account for this sync not being pulled across. Is there any other location that could be searched to determine why this issue could happen?

I would like to understand further as to why this could happen, is this issue common with BigQuery and Firebase? Is there any recommended path to getting this sync back to 24 hours instead of 48 hours?

Comment: Hi, any news about this issue? I'm facing the same delay